# Pandas condition-based row elimination in DataFrame

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in with information stored in a column until an unknown row number. After this row number, the column only stores NaN values. However, throughout the column some random NaN values appear as well. I want a cumulation to check how many NaN values are repeated to determine the the last row storing information.

My code is as follows:

1. first, I create a NaN checker that accumulates the number of NaN values row after row
2. next, I checks whether the NaN checker exceeds a certain threshold (3 in this case)
3. last, if the threshold is exceeded, the subsequent rows are eliminated

> ```
> Check_NaN =
> Fruits['bananas'].isnull().astype(int).groupby(Fruits['bananas']
>                 .notnull().astype(int).cumsum()).sum()
> ```
>
> ```
> for row in Fruits:
>     for cell in row['bananas']:
>         if cell(Check_NaN) < 3:
>             sum_Fruits.update(Fruits)
>         else:
>             row.dropna(subset=['bananas'])
> ```

Below is a data sample for `Fruits['bananas']`. These are rows 110-130 from which the end of Excel-information in the DataFrame is indicated by the beginning of NaN values.

```
110         banana red
111    banana green
112      banana white
113         banana yellow
114    banana black
115       banana orange
116     banana purple
117     banana pink
118     banana blue
119     banana silver
120     banana grey
121     banana gold
122       banana white
123       banana orange
124                    --
125                   NaN
126                   NaN
127                   NaN
128                   NaN
129                   NaN
```

However, I do run into a problem that is in `for cell in row['bananas']:` which gives `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

To me this is confusing as I can not iterate over the rows that I want to eliminate the rows. I need reusable code as the beginning of NaN values is different for each Excel sheet. How can I write my script such that the threshold of 3 NaN values is understood and eliminates the rest of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you could look at the shift function in Pandas, then shift twice and check if all three values are `NaN`

Try this:

```
# Find the rows where itself and the two subsequent rows are null in the bananas column
All_three_null = Fruits[‘banana’].isna() & Fruits[‘banana’].shift(-1).isna() & Fruits[‘banana’].shift(-2).isna()

# Find the index of the first row where this happens
First_instance = Fruits[All_three_null].index.min()

# Filter the data to remove all the null rows
Good_data = Fruits[Fruits.index <= First_instance]
```

Another option which will be better if you want to move from 3 `NaNs` in a row to 30!

The basic idea is to group all the subsequent NaN occurances into a uniquely identifiable group, then find the first group that exceeds the set limit and use this group to filter the original DataFrame

```
NaN_in_a_Row = 3

Fruits['Row_Not_NaN'] = Fruits['banana'].notna()
Fruits['First_Nan_After_Not_Nan'] = Fruits['banana'].isna() & Fruits['banana'].shift(1).notna()
Fruits['Group_ID'] = (Fruits['Row_Not_Nan']+Fruits['First_Nan_After_Not_Nan']).cumsum()
Fruits['Number_of_Rows'] = 1

Filter = Fruits.groupby(['Group_ID'])['Number_of_Rows'].sum()
Filter = Filter[Filter["Number_of_Rows"]>=NaN_in_a_Row].Group_ID.min()

Fruits = Fruits[Fruits.Group_ID < Filter]
```

Comment: Hey Fred, thanks for your contribution. Your solution indeed eliminates null rows. However, even with four conditions in the first statement, it cuts off the rows at 125. By doing so, it does not result in three rows with null rows. Also I would prefer to have a more flexible approach to modify the number of null rows, i.e. a variable

Comment: Hi @Wizard, check out my other option.

Comment: Also can you explain what the issue is with cutting the DataFrame off at row 125? Is that not what you expected?

Comment: I will read your other option and answer you in the mean while. I do not want to eliminate the rows directly when the NaN's occur, as I merge multiple sheets and want to have some whitespace inbetween. Another option is to cut off at 125 and add whitespace manually

Comment: Your 2nd option gives KeyErrors for Row_not_Nan. I am not so experienced and do not see why this occurs. Do you know this? I like the approach of storing the NaN's separately

Comment: I like the approach of storing the NaN's separately. In the DataFrame I see that the two extra columns are created, but First_Nan_After_No_Nan is only TRUE for row 125. I would expect that it should be true for all subsequent rows from 125  right?

Comment: Personally I would manually add the white space, so that you can control the exact behaviour. I’m trying this all on my phone, so I cannot test what your error is, but reading your comment just above it seems like you’ve fixed the issue? Finally only row 125 should have a True value for First_Nan_After_No_Nan, as you’ll be performing a cumulative sum to generate a unique ID, you need all the subsequent values to be 0 or False

Comment: All right, I will do that. I will accept your answer, thanks again!

Comment: No worries! Glad I can help

Comment: Could you maybe help me out with an additional question? Your solution works for checking one column in an excel sheet. I have multiple excel sheets for which I want to do this, and also multiple excel files. I have a dictionary in which the excel files are stores as DataFrames and in each DataFrame I have a few sheets for which I want to do this procedure. However, creating loops over the DataFrames only result in applying your solution on a single sheet. How can I loop over these DataFrames?

Comment: The best way would be to load each sheet into it's own DataFrame within a list, then do a loop, `for sub_df in df_list:` then perform the above

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. However, the sheets are automatically stored in one dictionary. Should I manually transform the sheets to storage in a list? In the current try to iterate I receive TypeErrors that indicate that the sheets (DataFrames) are not iterable. Has this do do that these are DataFrames?

Comment: Hey Wizard, I think you need to post a new question for this, with some examples and code. That will help me understand your problem better, put a link on this chat thread and I’ll take a look!

Comment: Hi Fred, I have made progress in the loops and solved the issue. However, now I want to write the output in an existing sheet of Excel by which I run into problems. Are you familiar with these functions? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326537/pandas-excelwriter-how-can-data-be-appended-to-sheets-with-existing-data